# Set FORM recordset from SQL Server how to set form TextBox backcolor by value

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have set a form and set record set from SQL Server. How can I set every column if Date < today then backcolor to red?

This is my code:

```
sub Form_OnLoad()
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim con as ADODB.Connection

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con
.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerSQLExpress,1433;Initial   _ Catalog=MyDB;User ID=johndoe;Password=password"
.Open

End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
.ActiveConnection = con
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.CursorType = adOpenStatic
.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.Open "Select * from tblClients"
End With

set me.recordser = rs

rs.close
con.close

set rs = nothing
set con = nothing

end sub
```

Comment: Thank you @marc_s

Comment: If form is in Single view, VBA would work. Would have to cycle through all controls or explicitly name controls to format and set Backcolor property. If form is Continuous or Dataheet, use Conditional Formatting. However, CF available only for textboxes and comboboxes.

Comment: Should be a "t" instead of "r" and end of `me.recordser`.

Comment: sorry, I don't under stand , "t" ?

Comment: `Me.Recordset` instead of `me.recordser`.